# Combining values in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some numpy arrays with the same size MxN (SVM predicts). I need to create a new one with the same size but only with the higher values of each position. Example:

```
[[1,2,1,3],         [[2,1,5,1],          [[2,2,5,3],
 [2,5,2,1]]   and   [1,3,5,5]]   result   [2,5,5,5]]
 [4,1,3,1]]         [4,2,1,2]]            [4,2,3,2]]
```

The sum and the product are made like this: `predict = a * b * c`, where `a, b and c` are numpy arrays with the same size read from other predicts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) to compute the element-wise maximum between the input arrays.

```
A = np.array([[1,2,1,3], [2,5,2,1], [4,1,3,1]])
B = np.array([[2,1,5,1], [1,3,5,5], [4,2,1,2]])

C = np.maximum(A, B)

# array([[2, 2, 5, 3],
#        [2, 5, 5, 5],
#        [4, 2, 3, 2]])
```

Comment: Seems like the go-to and is fast!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
np.where(a>b,a,b)
```

Here `np.where` does selection between `a` and `b` based on the mask of `a>b`, thus simulating the selection of maximum among corresponding elements in `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.max()` on 0th axis:

```
>>> np.max((a,b), axis=0)
array([[2, 2, 5, 3],
       [2, 5, 5, 5],
       [4, 2, 3, 2]])
```